# How is the text/elements positioning achieved on this website

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you resize the browser window both vertically and horizontally, you will notice that the text/elements around the edge move closer or further away from the edge, always keeping an even distance from the browser window around all sides. How is this achieved?

http://www.themustafacelik.com/

Is it done with pure css or is there Javascript or jQuery involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses position:absolute and right,top,bottom,left: distances

For example the "All works" text uses

```
position:absolute;
top:calc(7vw - 6px);
right: calc(7vw - 6px);
```

Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/lofuhapitu/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thank you. this worked perfectly. One thing I don't understand though. What is the    '- 6px'.    for?

Comment: calc is a css function that can perform calculation. so 7vw is 7% of the view-port width. so if the window is 1000px, the element will be positioned 70px - 6px = 64px from the right side of the the window.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text shrinks is because the element is styled with a font-size unit of `vw` and so it responds to the width:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .home #col2 h2 {
        font: 500 normal 18vw/20vw 'Adelon'
    }
}
```

**NOTE::-** In my honest opinion you are better of setting the `font-size` in `rem` or `em` as `vw` is sometimes going to shrink the size of the font to something you did't quite expect. using `rem` or `em` you can adjust the font size of the root/parent element respectively and the child element will following suit.

Comment: Yes I read the same thing. I am quite new to coding but I read that it is best to put a base font size in the body in px, and then make all of your font sizes with a em or rem. That way I can simply adjust the font size in the body style and it will scale all fonts on the site. I think I have understood that correctly anyway.